# Does turn undead from different sources stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I've read somewhere on the Internet (in a Divine Metamagic build) that having levels as Cleric and Paladin lets you have twice the turn undead attempts per day.

**Is that true?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No**.

Shockingly, the rules specifically address this.  Looking at the [rules for multiclass characters](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/classes.html):

> **Class Features:** A multiclass character gets all the class features of all his or her classes but must also suffer the consequences of the special restrictions of all his or her classes. (Exception: A character who acquires the barbarian class does not become illiterate.)
>
> *In the special case of turning undead*, both clerics and experienced paladins have the same ability. If the character’s paladin level is 4th or higher, her effective turning level is her cleric level plus her paladin level minus 3.

I'd think that this makes it pretty clear that you get the ability only once (and thus have one set of turning attempts), but add your levels together to find your effective turning level.

In case you think this is ambiguous, the wording about familiars is much the same:

> In the special case of obtaining a familiar, both wizards and sorcerers have the same ability. A sorcerer/wizard stacks his sorcerer and wizard levels to determine the familiar’s natural armor, Intelligence score, and special abilities.

Here it is clear that the words "have the same ability" are intended to mean that you are only granted the ability once.  Otherwise a sorcerer/wizard would have two familiars, not the one implied by the second sentence.